# Reading the binary content of a file

Tags: c++

I have a university assignment and i need to have some sort of function that detects the presence of a binary sequence (in my case, it should be a "virus" signature -> the assignment is to create some sort of antivirus that checks files for viruses ) in a file. To do this i believe i need to get the whole binary content of the file, and check the presence of that signature. The problem is that every function i found gives me the content of the file, not the raw binary data. Any ideas how i should proceed with this? Thanks !

Comment: ??  All files contain bytes of binary data.

Comment: do a little more research: when you open a file, the second argument is the mode for which you open the file.  there is a binary mode option. google this

Comment: I did, i used the "rb" argument;  This is my first time posting a question, i guess it was a bit ambigous because i am in a hurry. What i want is not the actual content from  file. For example, if the file contained a bit of text, i dont't want to get the text, but the bytes of information from the file, in hex value or something like this

Comment: **Post the code** that you asset doesn't work. If it as short and failed as you say, it should be obvious where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks! that is what i was looking for, but i didn't know exactly what to search

Answer (score 0):

I think you would use: [istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/)